# the shortest even path to minimum weight perfect matching

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

Given an edge weighted undirected graph and two vertices s and t, weights are non-negative.
Shortest Even Path Problem is to find an s,t-path P having an even number of edges whose total weight is as small as possible. How to reduce Shortest Even Path Problem to  minimum weight perfect matching problem

Comment: I understand "minimum weight", but what does "minimum weight perfect matching" mean?

Answer (score 1):

Start with the given graph, imagine painting the nodes blue, and call it G<sub>blue</sub>. It has nodes, including s<sub>blue</sub> and t<sub>blue</sub>, and undirected edges like a<sub>blue</sub> <-> b<sub>blue</sub>.

Make a copy of the graph, paint its nodes green and call it G<sub>green</sub>.

Now reconnect all of the edges, so that a<sub>blue</sub><->b<sub>blue</sub> and a<sub>green</sub><->b<sub>green</sub> (which have equal weights) become a<sub>blue</sub><->b<sub>green</sub> and a<sub>green</sub><->b<sub>blue</sub> (which have the same weights).

In this combined graph, every edge is between a blue node and a green node, so every path alternates between blue and green. So every path from s<sub>blue</sub> that has a even number of steps, will end on a green node.

Now on this combined graph, seek the minimum-weight path from s<sub>blue</sub> to t<sub>green</sub>.

Finally, remove the subscripts.

Comment: could give a picture, because it's difficult to understand?

Comment: @user424603: Which part is difficult to understand?

Comment: in the beginning we paint all vertices to blue?

Comment: and where do we use minimum weight perfect matching?

Comment: @user424603: Yes, imagine they are blue. That is a way to imagine the set of nodes of that graph, as distinct from the nodes of the other graph. If you dislike blue, you can use some other subscript. And we use "minimum weight perfect matching" in the second-to-last step, "...seek the minimum-weight path..."

Comment: "Now reconnect all of the edges, so that ablue<->bblue and agreen<->bgreen (which have equal weights) become ablue<->bgreen and agreen<->bblue (which have the same weights)." Do we add edge between graph copies or we repaint the graph?

Comment: @user424603: I'm sorry, but I don't think I can help you.

Comment: what do u mean?